# Anyone experiencing slow WPF application with RDLC reports?

Tags: wpf, xsd, performance, rdlc

I have an WPF application for 60 users tops.

Some of they are cashier users, and I use RDLC reports to show customer orders.
The problem is, users are telling that application is getting slow or hanging.

This WPF application uses most up-to-date Enterprise Library. Connection pooling is handled by default, there's no customization.

RDLC files use dataset XSD files. XSD files use database stored procedures to select data.

On xsd files used by RDCL I have something like:

```
Data Source=Junior-PC;Initial Catalog=FoodAndBeverage;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mypass
```

On c# code-behind, the static connection string:

```
Data Source=Junior-PC;Initial Catalog=FoodAnBeverage;User ID=sa;Password=mypass;Connection Timeout=4
```

Every 30 seconds I also have a DispatcherTimer to check if Database Server IP is found.

Anyone having similar problems regarding this slow WPF application issue using RDLC? Would it be a problem with WindowsFormsHost getting slow, which shows RDLC reports?

What could I do to speed up?

Comment: I have made some tests, on each RDLC impression, memory is getting small on user computer's memory. I'm thinking about isolate RDLC, migrate them to a light weight WPF / Win32 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was looking for a solution of another problem of reportviewer (rdlc), I've seen a remark of Brian Hartman, that the report viewer 2010 has a fix for some memory issues. Googling about memory leaks showed me among others this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/d21f8b56-3123-4aff-bf84-9cce727bc2ce

Please note that using ReportViewer 2010 has currently some compatibility-problems (and a new rdlc-format). Test it before using.

Comment: One the of the first things I've done was do download the service pack for Report Viewer 2008 SP1. And on C# code behind, now I'm releasing memory by setting null to these rdlc and dataset objects and then calling Garbage Collector. The memory now is more stable: keeps growing some times but eventually it's reduced near where it should be when running the app for the first time.